# Need help in extracting info from multiple html files [req: batch/c++/notepad script]

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have about 100+ files from which I need to extract certain info and copy them to separate files. They're all html files, and have html coding.
File format:

```
<html>
<head>
...
... useless text ..
</head>
<body>
.. useless text ..
<div class="container">
<div class="another container">
<div class="heading_container">

important text 
<table> ... important table contents </table>
important text
</div> //.../heading 
</div> //garbage div close..
</div>/// etc etc closing divs..
<div class="clear"></div> 
//above line is in all the files... so maybe the script could be written to copy all until this div (?) .
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I require to copy all the text under `<div class="heading_container">` ...

Any idea how I could do that in a batch script? Or some html software to do it in a batch software?

I don't know much about batch scripting, but maybe the script could hold a for / while loop to copy text to a file:

```
variable string_start = '<div class="heading_container">';
variable string_end = '<div class="clear">';
get file("FILE_URL");
READ the file until `string_start` is reached.
output from 'string start' onwards, to a different folder with same filename.
stop output once string_end is reached.
stop read from the file.
```

Could this be done? I'm not too good at algorithms syntax too!

Comment: If your content has divs in it, its gonna be problem. Only useful stuff I have discovered so far for that case is PHP based HTML DOM parser. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm 
See if you can reverse engineer it and write in batch or something else

Comment: @tumchaaditya: I tried that PHP project as well... I was able to view a php created page with the following script: `foreach($html->find('div.heading') as $e)  echo $e->innertext . '<br>'; ` ... my php file also included `include(php_file)` and `$html=file_get_html('source_html_file)`. But I don't know how to output the php generated code to txt or html automatically. The code giving output is probably `echo $e->innertext` and I don't know how to create a loop for this to output that into txt or html files..?

Comment: You can use directoryiterator(http://de.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) to loop over files and file_put_contents(http://us1.php.net/file_put_contents) to write to separate files inside the loop

Comment: @tumchaaditya: I got that working successfully! Thanks! Now could you please also provide a solution to next problem? : How can I copy all code from these new generated html files > TO a html template between `<div class="new_data">` and `<div class="end_new_data">` or something similar? Also, please post your answer, so that I can Select it as your answer. I've copied my version of script to this page: http://pastebin.com/XwgsGKAF  ... Directory structure here: http://i.imgur.com/KvQUGn2.jpg

Comment: Done. I have used your script partially and mentioned that credit goes to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is going to have `<div>` then your script/code will have to smart enough to identify the matching closing `</div>`.
I found a PHP based solution that can do this. Find it here: PHP HTML DOM Parser(http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

You can use this in combination with `directoryiterator` and `file_put_contents` to write files with contents in a loop.
If you want to insert this into an HTML template you can save your HTML template with some discernible text in place of actual content you want to put like this:

```
<div class="new_data">
replace_me_discernible_text_not_appearing_anywhere_else_in_file
</div>
```

Then you can replace this text with your content.
Here's a complete script to do it (*Script partial credit goes to OP. I am pasting here for future reference*):

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$destdir = "extracted_html";
$oldMessage = "replace_me_discernible_text_not_appearing_anywhere_else_in_file";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("content_html");
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo)
        {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot())
                {
                $file_name = basename($fileinfo);
                $html = file_get_html("content_html/$file_name");
                foreach($html->find('div.heading') as $e)
                        {

                        $str=file_get_contents('template.html');
                        $str=str_replace($oldMessage, $e,$str);
                        file_put_contents("$destdir/$file_name", $str);
                        echo $file_name . " <b>Done!</b> </br>";
                        }
                }
        }
?>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Hi! There's a slight error in this script: All the files' content is being replaced by a single file, and not separate files. ie, the filenames are being copied the same, but the content is only being copied from a single html file, not all separate. Could this be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know what i changed, but the script is functional now... thanks again!

Comment: Can you diff my script with your working version and update changes here for future visitors? Probably something is fishy with innermost each..

Comment: You should probably concat content inside innermost each(to take care if you have multiple div.heading in single file) and do file write operations just outside innermost each.

Comment: I don'y understand what you mean by concat, but I found no difference between your version of script and my version. Maybe I might have missed a `'` or `"` in `template.html` while changing the template.html string for other content. Anyways, here my version of the script, without much changes..: http://pastebin.com/9HZgNpTm ...

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done with a [Windows port of PCREGREP](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm) and the following command:

```
for %%i in (*.html) do (
  pcregrep -N CRLF -M -o "<div class="""heading_container""">(.+?)</div>" "%%i" ^
  > "%%~ni.cpp"
)
```

If you have extra `div`s in the middle, then you can use this line in the `for` loop instead to extract until the clearing `div`:

```
  …
  pcregrep -N CRLF -M -o "<div class="""heading_container""">(.+?)<div class="""clear""">" "%%i" ^
  …
```

**Figure 1**: Test results

[image: Screenshot of test results]

Comment: That code displayed an error: http://i.imgur.com/XNFP2ao.jpg

Comment: `file_run.bat` is the file I copied your code to...

Comment: If you are using it in a batch-file, then you have to double the percent signs; replace all `%` with `%%`.

Comment: @Synetech: This will work only if there are no sub-divs inside header div. Otherwise it will end on closing of first sub-div

Comment: @tumchaaditya, it will work for the examples that mk has given. If they have different data or further requirements (like excluding the outer tags—though they would still have the table tags), then they can edit the question as needed. Updated to support middle `div`s anyway.

Comment: Hi Synetech: I tried the new code, but got an error: ` 'pcregrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch program`. ... Maybe I've not been able to install it correctly.. I installed version pcre-7.0 from this link: `http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/pcre/` .. It installed to `program files/gunwin32/` on windows xp (virtualbox)

Comment: It needs to either be in your [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#DOS.2C_OS.2F2.2C_and_Windows) or the current directory. The easiest solution would be to download the file [`pcregrep.exe`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/pcre/7.0/pcre-7.0-bin.zip/download?use_mirror=superb-dca2) and extract it to the directory containing all of your `.html` files and run it from there, or just edit the batch-file and replace `pcregrep` with the full path to where you installed it (for example, `"c:\program files\gnuwin\pcregrep.exe"`—don’t forget the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a simple version of what you

```
#!/bin/sh 
for X in $(find ./ -name "*.html")
    do
    FN=$(echo $X | cut -d '/' -f 3)
    cat $X | awk '/^< div class=\"heading_container\" >/,/< div class=\"clear\"><\/div >/  { print }' > ./new/$FN   
    done
```

If all your files are in sub dir called old under a dir called files. Run this from the files dir, it will strip out the information you want and dump it into the same file name in the dir ./files/new.

This is fairly hacky, and will not work if there are sub dirs in old.

I might have a look at enhancing this and will update if I can do better.

**UPDATE**

Even though I have been told the target for this is windows here is a more complete bash script that might help someone in future.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd old

# Create the directory structure in the 'new' directory 

for Z in $(find ./ -type d)
        do
        Z=$(echo $Z | tr -d '.')
        mkdir ../new/$Z
        done
cd ..
# Find all relevent files snip the interesting bit and copy to the same file in ../new 

for X in $(find ./ -name "*.html")
        do
        FN=$(echo $X | cut -d '/' -f 3-100)
        cat $X | awk '/^< div class=\"heading_container\" >/,/< div class=\"clear\"><\/div >/  { print }' > ./new/$FN
        done
```

The main caveat is to remove (backup and remove) the 'new' directory before running.

Comment: The OP was talking about Windows, not Linux !

Comment: Eeeik .... misread batch as bash. Also I'm not allowed comment above, but I think the script needs to stop when it reaches '< div class=\"clear\">' so not the entire rest of the file.

Comment: Well in fairness to James, doing such things on Windows is needlessly difficult, so it makes sense to just answer for a sensible platform and tell the OP to "get a real operating system!" :)    Really, though... a fairly simple MinGW installation would make this script a valid Windows solution.

Comment: If there is a consensus to delete I have no problem. But other than say batch file there is no indication that the q is windows exclusive. Finally even if this solution does not help the OP it may help any one with a similar problem on a different platform.

Comment: `But other than say batch file there is no indication that the q is windows exclusive.` You mean other than the `windows` tag?

Comment: Ahhh sorry .. I posted my last comment from my phone. But I stand by my position that it is still useful for my 'wrong for this platform' solution to remain, as it is still useful for someone else. I have used serverfault regularly and very often I find that answer I need is not the accepted answer but one below. But as I said if the consensus is to delete I can understand -- J

Comment: Delete it?  Don't be silly!  This is, in fact, a highly acceptable answer on Windows.   There's no law against installing bash for Windows or MinGW or Cygwin or unixutils.  A batch file would be a lousy solution, even if you could somehow get the parsing to work. The only other "Native" windows solution which doesn't involve installing a tool that might or might not be present already is VBscript, and that sucks too for this problem.   So in fact, this solution is at least as good as the alternatives, and offers the chance of introducing the OP to *nix concepts.

Comment: Bear in mind that the suggestion of using .Net or C++ is no better -- both would require installation of tools that aren't in the base platform, and the problem does not involve accessing Windows APIs, which might give other tools an advantage over bash.

Comment: Hey! I do have Linux Mint 15 on Virtual Box, so yes, I can run linux bash scripts too! but I've never heard or known about bash scripts.. I'm trying to learn about it on google, but still don't understand, certain things: What's `CD old` being used for? Where & in what format to save this script?

Comment: I have a folder named `orignal`, for all the html files. Is it simple to create a folder `content` in ` Documents` folder of `/home`. & then copy this `original` folder to that `content` folder, & run the script? That way the `original` folder's files will be scanned & the new files could be created in the `content/new` folder.

Comment: Hey mk,  So if I understand what you are saying all of your files are in a folder called original.  so in /home create a folder call 'work' (mkdir work). copy original to work 'cp -dpr <path>/original /home/work' change into the work folder. 'cd /home/work'. using your favourite editor open a new file called process.sh.  Copy the code from above into it.(change where it says 'old' to 'content'. run the following 'chmod 755 process.sh'  then finally run ./process.sh. The files will processed and be sent to /home/work/new.  Best of luck